# Infinitely repeating class of divs with an absolute position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I am trying to build a page on which a set of divs repeat infinitely. 
Because the divs are all absolutely positioned, it seems as though scrolling plugins that repeat the divs just overlay them on the same location, which looks like nothing. 
How can I repeat an entire series of divs or so with every scroll?

This is a sample of the CSS and the html:

```
.square 
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
} 

#one 
{
    background-color: #3a5496;
    top: 20px; 
    left: 50px; 
}

<body>
    <div class="square" id="one">  </div> 
    <div class="square" id="two">  </div>
</body>
```

There are over 40 individual divs that essentially do the same thing, only spread out across 3000 pixels. I gave each div an id like "#one."

Answer (score 0):

Absolute position will always remain in the same place where top:0; is the top of the content window.

try using relative positioning where top:0; is the point following the div above it.

Comment: When I change the position to "relative," all of the divs skew into an odd waterfall down the page. Here is what it looks like with absolute positioning: http://people.reed.edu/~tamanaka/absolute.html     and here is how it warps with relative: http://people.reed.edu/~tamanaka/relative.html

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? a long line of divs that go from top to bottom and continue to scroll?  Stacked 1 on top of another?

Comment: I want the entire collection of divs to repeat. so yeah they would stack but not one at a time, but the entire group over and over

Comment: onscroll, clone the div and append them to the body.

Comment: If you go the absolute positioning route you'll have to introduce new values for top and left, if you use relative position you'll have to adjust the current top and left position, but then you shouldn't have to adjust the values when you clone the elements.